# Mac Mini (summer 2011) and Dell U2711 - How to get the maximum resolution 2560x1440?

Tags: display, mac-mini, resolution, thunderbolt-display

I've been using the Mac Mini with Dell U2711 monitor for couple days and only now I've realized what is wrong: The display isn't using its maximum resolution 2560x1440 but the 1080p which the OS reports as the max resolution. I then read from the Apple's site that for some reason 1080p is the maximum resolution when using the HDMI-connector.

The Mac Mini contains only HDMI and Thunderbolt connectors, at least according to Apple's site. The Dell-monitor doesn't have Thunderbolt but instead it has VGA, DVI, DisplayPort and HDMI.

So my question is: Is it possible to get the maximum resolution out of my monitor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thunderbolt contains a DisplayPort channel.  You can get a Thunderbolt/Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable.  I found a cheap one on [Monoprice](http://monoprice.com) a while back. [Here](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024606&p_id=6007&seq=1&format=2) is a 6 footer.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you linked to the actual cable you bought from them rather than just the site.

Comment: *This* is the answer. Thunderbolt uses the same connector as Mini DisplayPort, since they're compatible. MiniDP-to-DP cables are available pretty much everywhere @cksum

Comment: You're right, cksum. Just added a link.

Comment: So MiniDP to DVI adapter doesn't work, it must be MiniDP to DisplayPort?

Comment: Single-link DVI can't drive the monitor at it's native resolution, but Display Port certainly can.

Answer (score 4):

Only via Thunderbolt.

As you said, Apple's [documentation for the Mac mini (Mid 2011)](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP632) states:

> #### Video Support
>
> - Thunderbolt port with support for up to 2560-by-1600 resolution
> - HDMI port with support for up to 1920-by-1200 resolution

It [used to be possible](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp505) with models using a dual-link DVI Adapter which the new models don't support:

> Simultaneously supports up to 1920 by 1200 pixels on a DVI or VGA display; up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on a dual-link DVI display using Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter.